# I won a bounty in Chess Stack Exchange although it does not show up on my profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties

I won a bounty question but under my profile it shows I have never earned any bounties. It's a discrepancy.

Details here:

Bounty Winning answer on Chess Stack Exchange: [Major Chess 960 tournaments?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/major-chess-960-tournaments/2065#2065)

[image: Bounty Winning Answer]

My Profile Bounties column is empty
[image]

- I am not sure whom should I report to?
- Let me know if any of you see anything different on my profile?

Comment: I see it just fine, are you sure you're viewing the correct site?

Comment: Shows up when I view it. Probably caching. It's always caching. http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/1065/pal4life?tab=bounties&sort=earned

Comment: @Billy bounty was awarded over a year ago so doubt it's caching this time.

Comment: @Sha I said "always" and I meant "always"! :P (But yeah, had the comment written just before I saw the date.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks fine here. Are you sure you're looking at the right site?

[image]

Comment: You plagiarized my comment! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard And this is why we don't post answers as comments. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at my profile in Stackoverflow. The way it is structured currently, you see all your account summary just above the bounties column. That gave me the understanding that it is referring to my bounties on all the other stackexchange accounts as well.

This is just a user interface thing as per me. Thus if you look at this. There is a chance to get confused. Thus if the language was made more explicit there as in **0 earned bounties in Stack Overflow**, it would be more clear.

[image]

Comment: Why did you hide your reputation on the different sites? Anyone can [see it](http://stackoverflow.com/users/805923/pal4life#user-panel-accounts).